# android OutOfMemoryError while restoring pictures from cache

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, out-of-memory

My app has a GridView, where each item is ImageView. I wrote custom adapter to set images into  ImageViews. Images sets asynchronously using AsyncTask

My AsyncTask to restore image from cache

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
   return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        // load image from db
    }
}
```

The GridView placed on fragment. After sever fragment replacements I've got an OutOfMemoryError at the line `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());`

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=131079KB, Allocated=126797KB)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:658)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:347)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:430)
            at com.ThreeBoots.utils.ImageProcessor$2.doInBackground(ImageProcessor.java:248)
            at com.ThreeBoots.utils.ImageProcessor$2.doInBackground(ImageProcessor.java:245)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Help me please to fix this problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not load the bitmap directly into memory. Define what sizes the resulting bitmap should be and load a scaled version of the bitmap using the technique described here:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

first you have to declare largeheap size in your manifest.and use the bitmap recycle according to your code.
for manifest.xml 
android:largeHeap="true"

```
if (bm != null) {

    bm.recycle();
    bm = null;

}
```

hope it will work for you.

Comment: `android:largeHeap=true` should be avoided mostly and must be the last resort.

Comment: Have u used bitmap recycle?

Comment: I have, but my app crashes with message 'Cannot draw recycled bitmaps'